# How to remove all dots from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

Can someone explain line 7? I know that in the end, all commas are replaced by dots, but how does that work? And what should I do if I want to remove all the dots from the CSV file (without pandas)?

```py
def collector(request):
    with open("C:\\Users\\Simon\\Dev\\Water\\src\\csv\\items_water.csv") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            if row == [] or row[1] == "products":
                continue
            price = float(str(row[1].split(",")[0]) + "." + row[1].split(",")[1])
            print(price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important lines :

```py
row[1]           # take the second element of row,
  .split(",")[0] # split it on commas and takes the first part of it
                 # "123,456" => "123"

  .split(",")[1] # Does the same thing but with the second part of it
```

With this, if `row[1]` was `"123,456"` we would get `"123" + "." + "456"`

This is then cast into a string(most likely useless) then into a float

A much simpler way to accomplish this would be
`price = row[1].replace(',', '.', 1)`

To remove all the dots from a string, simply use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) like above but by ommiting the last paramter count.

Comment: That worked fine, but my problem is that I need to remove all the points from the CSV file and then replace all points with commas. How am I supposed to do that? Both must be done in a variable, since I'll use that variable later and save the CSV data in my database.